# Authlogic Facebook Connect/Twitter oAuth helper issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, facebook, authlogic

I am a complete newbie to the world of Ruby & Rails moving from the land of PHP & Symfony. I'm currently attempting to setup the Facebook Connect plugin & Twitter oAuth for authlogic. Authlogic works no problem but both of the others fail when I attempt to call their buttons- can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? I've put the stack trace below- thanks!

---

```
NameError in User_sessions#new

Showing app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml where line #13 raised:

undefined local variable or method `authlogic_facebook_login_button' for #<ActionView::Base:0x1034fe9e0>

Extracted source (around line #13):

= f.text_field :password
%br
= f.submit "Login"
= authlogic_facebook_login_button



RAILS_ROOT: /Users/nick/Sites/matchmefor-2
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

/Users/nick/Sites/matchmefor-2/app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:13:in `_run_haml_app47views47user_sessions47new46html46haml'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.2.9/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:164:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.2.9/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:164:in `form_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.2.9/lib/haml/helpers.rb:543:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.2.9/lib/haml/helpers.rb:543:in `haml_bind_proc'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.2.9/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:170:in `form_for'
/Users/nick/Sites/matchmefor-2/app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:4:in `_run_haml_app47views47user_sessions47new46html46haml'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.2.9/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.2.9/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.2.9/lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:19:in `process
```

Comment: Have you restarted your server after installing the plugin ?

Comment: *sigh*, I'm such a fool- I should have known it would be something simple. Thanks for the help!